# Setup ended prematurely with error but works with msiexec /i

Tags: wix

When I double click my installer I'm greeted with a "Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified ..."

Strangely though, when I run it with msiexec /i from a command line, it works fine

Any clues as to what might be causing this or how I can diagnose the problem?

Is there a way to figure out what the command line / parameters is when you double click an MSI so that I can log it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a quick check with RegEdit, a `.msi` file is a `msi.package` file, and checking that filetype shows that the default `Shell->Open` action is

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "%1" %*
```

So the action taken when you double-click it is `msiexec.exe /i <file clicked>` unless you have a shortcut set up to add additional command-line parameters for that particular `.msi` file.

Comment: Bingo got it. Useful to know. And thankfully, helped me get to the root of the real, underlying error. It was working from the commandline because I was running it from PowerShell and it was ultimately a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this

```
<Product>
...
</Product>
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="Service">
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp7463D4C60D83B5CE6102AB619B8353DF" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmpBA2F0EC85506BB1F776AE401395C2C15" />
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

But I had to change it on something like this. After that it works.

```
<Feature Id="Service" Title="Service" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp7463D4C60D83B5CE6102AB619B8353DF" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpBA2F0EC85506BB1F776AE401395C2C15" />
</Feature>
```